# How to prevent a user from selecting a specific fragment in viewpager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 5 fragments. 
On certain selection in fragment 0 and 1 I want to disable the user from accessing fragment 2 (because it is will be empty based on the user selection in fragment 0 and 1).
The user should be able to access fragment 4 and 5.
When the user changes the selection on either fragment 0 or 1 so that there will be data displayed in fragment 2. I want the user to be able to access it.
My application knows when there is no data to be displayed on fragment 2.

I tried doing it by storing in memory the last fragment displayed, and when the user swipes to fragment 2 and there is no data to displayed I then called 
    tabLayout.getTabAt(myLastTab).select();
from within
    onPageSelected(int position)
It works but but after few tries to displayed fragment 2 my application crashes with 'stack overflow' error.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: Issue is solved. I change the logic of my application so that I remove the tab from the TabLayout.

Comment: well make an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic of my application so that I remove the tab from the TabLayout, and therefore the user does not see the tab and there is no need to skip it.